# Warning message using ant design dynamic form

Tags: reactjs

I am using ant design dynamic form like this:  https://codesandbox.io/s/wsuv8 .
I have separated the form items also using `div` tag like:

```js
   

      <div className="my-div">
                          <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, "first"]}
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                          >
                            <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                          </Form.Item>
 </div>
 <div className="my-div">
                          <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, "last"]}
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                          >
                            <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                          </Form.Item>
  </div>
```

When i add new inputs, in my project, clicking on `Add field` button i get the next warning:

```css
Encountered two children with the same key, `0`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

*This warning disappears when i delete `div` tags between inputs.*

I now that this warning appears when forget to set the `key` for the items inside `map()` for example, but in my case the key is set for the component that wrap the entire form:

```js
  

  <Space
         key={field.key} // the key is set here
         style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
        align="start"
     >
```

Question: Why the warning appears if the key is set in `<Space>` component and how to solve the issue?

Comment: @Pirhan, could you take a look, please

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should get name and key with object destructuring and get ...restFields, then spread restFields to formItem

```
{fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }, index) => (
   <Form.Item
    {...restField}
    name={[name, 'columnName']}
   />
   ....
   ....
   ....
)}
```